# Create truststore for StartSSL Certificate

Tags: java, ssl, wildfly, keytool

I'm trying to create a truststore from StartSSL certificates to enable http2 in Wildfly 10.

So far I have tried this [script](https://gist.github.com/J0s3f/8ca5a90502a8f9e0abe7) and the instructions in this [link](https://forum.startcom.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=1678).

So I executed the commands below:

```
wget http://www.startssl.com/certs/ca.cr
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore truststore -alias startcom.ca -file ca.crt
wget http://www.startssl.com/certs/sub.class1.server.ca.crt
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore truststore -alias startcom.ca.sub.class1 -file sub.class1.server.ca.crt
```

The first keytool command works ok, but I get get the following error in the last command:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Answer** - These are the correct files:

```
wget http://www.startssl.com/certs/ca.cr
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore truststore -alias startcom.ca -file ca.crt
wget https://www.startssl.com/certs/ca-g2.crt
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore truststore -alias startcom.ca-g2 -file ca-g2.crt
wget https://www.startssl.com/certs/ca-sha2.crt
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore truststore -alias startcom.ca-sha2 -file ca-sha2.crt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing it wrong. It is the second file (**sub.class1.server.ca.crt**) which you might have downloaded, is wrong. Upon inspection, the file had invalid data in it.

You can view this yourself by opening that file in a text editor, you might see this data - *class1/sha2/der/sub.class1.server.sha2.ca.crt*.

If you need the whole chain, you could grab it from any browser. Just click the **green lock** on the address bar, which will open the native Certificate Viewer, through which you can choose to download individual certificates or the whole chain.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I found the correct files and I added to my main post.